# Why isn't the moon's surface made of mini craters?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-formation, meteorite

I thought that the millions of mini rocks that hit the moon would cause it to be entirely cratered and not flat.

Why is the moon not like this:

[image]

why aren't craters visible in the footprint photo?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how the top photograph was made? I doubt it accurately simulates particles sequentially impacting the lunar surface at ~30 km/s from a variety of angles in a low gravity environment. You also have to consider the spectrum of sizes of the impactors and whether any resurfacing has occured since the impacts.

Comment: There _are_ many craters on the moon. I would suspect that the second photo doesn't show an area large enough for craters to be visible

Comment: The top photograph is what I naively imagine the moon would look like based on the size distribution of space rocks. Account taken of the dispersion of dust by big meteorites, I suppose that 1000 tiny meteorites land after every sizeable one... I'm wondering why the moon surface wouldnt easily present a random array of exotic rocks as those that occur on asteroids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice question, unfortunately your analoguous experiment is not as analoguous as you might hope.

In your comparison image you are using both, not enough impactors, and a too tiny size distribution. Impactors on the Moon (or any other objects) follow a reasonably [well-known size distribution](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1997M%26PS...32..179H) where the smaller an impactor is, the more frequent collisions with those do occur.

The visible and measured / counted size distribution of craters on the Moon follows this probability law quite well (e.g. [this paper (Cross, 1966)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1966MNRAS.134..245C/0000245.000.html), but many others get about identical results). The main difference is that in your comparison you miss all the very tiny impactors which smooth-out the surface again.

Further, the Moon is covered with loose regolith of about [45µm diameter](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103512004939). In the sunlight it is subject to charging and thus the Moon surface is covered by a tiny sheet of [statically elevated particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_soil). This leads to a re-distribution of the surface regolith particles, smoothing out the tiniest craters even more.

Even further, the [landing sites](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/50-years-ago-lunar-landing-sites-selected) of Apollo were carefully chosen to be the most level and crater-free places to ensure a safe landing. The amount of cratering in a particular place is also random, even when all the surface is covered by [several layers of craters (this is a study for asteroids, but applies to other bodies, too)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02340).

And further more, your comparison experiment is conducted in air. That affects the formation of craters and in particular the [distribution of ejecta](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s40645-018-0222-5) due to friction with air, more so, the smaller the impactors get and the slower the ejecta are.

Comment: Great answer.  Also surface gravity on the Moon is much lower than surface gravity on Earth, so the ejecta tend to travel further, and hence be distributed more evenly.

Comment: There's also topographic diffusion and seismic shaking which will remove small craters.